# intellij idea internal java compiler error

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am running a simple pattern matcher program exactly as in 
[test_harness](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/test_harness.html)

```
Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'demo_java8'
Information:javac 1.8.0_121 was used to compile java sources
Information:2018-02-06 10:15 - Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 376ms
Error:java: Compilation failed: internal java compiler error
```

However terminal command `javac xxx.java` and `java xxx` run properly.

Running the first hello world program gives the same error.

Comment: Try upgrading Java and set Intellij to use it?

Comment: @cricket_007 why upgrade? 1.8 is too low for this class?

Comment: You can keep 1.8, but 121 is not the latest build

Comment: I'm mostly  curious about what `java -version` in the terminal returns

Comment: @cricket_007 I think this is intellij idea's problem not java version. Because it starts OK with a hello world program, then it was not OK with `test_harness` and after that it was not OK for hello world. Maybe I could check license and upgrade intellij idea.

Comment: it is 1.8.0_121

Comment: Intellij doesn't need a license. But you should definitely upgrade both, in case any case

Comment: @HonzaZidek 2017.2

Answer (score 12):

In my case, the issue is resolved by adding a type parameter object to a class instance that needed it. In the following code replaced `new ParameterizedTypeReference<>` with `new ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, Object>>`

```
return getRestTemplate().exchange(uri,
                                  HttpMethod.POST,
                                  new HttpEntity<>(headers),
                                  new ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {

                                  });
```

Comment: OH MY GOD. I wasted a whole day figuring out why my build failing. And all that because IntelliJ IDEA suggested to omit explicit type in `ParameterizedTypeReferenc`: Explicit type argument CommandResponse<JsonNode> can be replaced with <>

Answer (score 3):

It turned out that "odd" error description is because of maven plugin was missing. And it's default was 1.5 while `Console` class is only available since 1.6. Instead of `jar or class cannot be found`, it gives a blur description `internal java compiler error`. `Information:javac 1.8.0_121 was used to compile java sources` was a hint that the javac version and sdk version mismatch. Besides, I was surprised that intellij idea run function uses `maven build` (I thought it was just for cli) .

Comment: Well, is it a a Maven project then? Or if not, *where* was the Maven configuration missing? BTW, when you configure Maven for a different than the default Java version, you are in fact **not** *adding* the plugin, it is there anyway - so probably what you wanted to say was that "a maven plugin *configuration* was missing" :) Maven has a lot of plugins pre-configured by default.

Comment: In my case I had build plugin maven-compiler-plugin set to 1.6 and project's jdk set to 1.8. This was resulting in not so informative "internal java compiler error" by Intellij IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

If I have to guess, your IntelliJ is using the JDK packed with IntelliJ, try to set up your JDK for your project, in Project Structure make sure the JDK match your Java environment. 
[JDK selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDzQ1.png)

Comment: I was wondering the same. Although the phenomena was it first ok, and then not ok...

Answer (score 0):

If you use a maven project and for example, you use java version as 1.8 please use this plugin where you specify which version you are using.
Working example:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```